# CSS unicode font

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, font-face, webfonts

I am surprised to see few websites where they have kept normal unicode font (tamil language). But while displaying the website it is seen not as a normal unicode font but it looks more attractive and stylish.

For example: http://dinakaran.com/News_Detail.asp?Nid=33281

How it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are custom fonts loaded on the listed example via CSS. So, you have to use utf-8 encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And configure your custom fonts via CSS and `@font-face` to get the same effect.

```
@font-face {font-family: 'DINAKARAN2W'; src: ... }
body { font-family:"DINAKARAN2W",... }
```